# Particle effect on collision?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision, particle-system

This is a simple question. I did it a couple of times already, don't know why I can't get it done now...
I made a particle effect, I want this to get played when the player collides with the platform.
Here's what I've done:

```
public class StartingPlatformFall : MonoBehaviour
{
    //public GameObject smoke;
    //public GameObject spawn;
    public ParticleSystem smoke;

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            //Instantiate(smoke, spawn.transform, Quaternion.identity);
            smoke.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The smoke particle effect will be playing somewhere else. After the collision, get the position of the player and instantiate the particle prefab over there.

```
Instantiate(smoke prefab, player  position, player rotation);
particle.play();
```

Comment: Actually, there is no movement. Right at the beginning, the player falls down to the starting platform. This is the collision where I want to play a smoke effect.

Comment: okay then place the prefab in the starting point.

Comment: It is already. The problem is, that it's not starting by colliding. There is something wrong with the code, I guess. No clue what.

Comment: Try to debug some output, If it collided with the player. if not, make sure the player has a rigid body and the object collider doesn't have is trigger.

Comment: Yes, I already found out what the problem was. Can you helo me with one last thing? Can you tell me how to enable that specific ParticleSystem from another script? I want to move it from "StartingPlatformFall" script to the "GameManager" script, right into this statement:
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                GameStart();
            } - this basically means, as soon as I click on the mouse button, the game starts. I want to stop the particle effect right here.

Comment: FindObjectOfType<otherScriptName>().particleName.play();

Comment: Oh lord, I swapped it, started with the script name, that's why I was lost, haha. Thank you a lot for helping me out!